# Disable the button when fields are empty in Angular5 [ invalid form ]

Tags: angular, angular-validation

I am learning Angular5, new to this.

I have two input fields, one button. Handled validations for that two fields,  will enable the button once two fields are entered. I have disable the button when the form is invalid. But it is not working.

```
<form class="customerRegisteration-form">  
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input required ngModel name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"  placeholder="First Name" #firstName="ngModel"/>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.touched && !firstName.valid">First Name is required</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input required ngModel name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" #lastName="ngModel"/>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="lastName.touched && !lastName.valid">Last Name is required</div>    
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" [disabled]="!customerRegisteration.valid">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Kindly help me if anything wrong.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just change the form tag to `<form class="customerRegisteration-form" #customerRegisteration="ngForm">`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Form should have  a formGroup as

```
<form  [formGroup]="customerRegisteration">
```

or

```
 <form class="customerRegisteration-form" #customerRegisteration="ngForm">
```

and then,

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" [disabled]="!customerRegisteration.valid">
```

Comment: if you type in a blank space this will be valid. How do you prevent blanks and empty space?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply add `#customerRegisteration="ngForm"` in your  tag like below

```
<form class="customerRegisteration-form" #customerRegisteration="ngForm">
```

Full code is

```
<form class="customerRegisteration-form" #customerRegisteration="ngForm">  
  <div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
      <input required ngModel name="firstName" id="firstName" class="form-control"  placeholder="First Name" #firstName="ngModel"/>
      <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="firstName.touched && !firstName.valid">First Name is required</div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
    <input required ngModel name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" #lastName="ngModel"/>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="lastName.touched && !lastName.valid">Last Name is required</div>    
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-info" [disabled]="!customerRegisteration.valid">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i> Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Note. I suggest you to read [Angular Forms Article](https://angular.io/guide/forms) as well as you have many questions about angular forms